# Auto Generated Key Google Services

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-api

Does anyone know why Google keeps generating new API keys or is it my app ? It's quite irritating seeing new generated keys without any concerns.

[image: Google developer console]

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, I came to realise whenever i tried downloading the google-services file from Firebase, Google re-generates new API keys for usage. It's best to stick with one file on your local PC if you don't want such behaviour to occur and bug you out.

And also i would suggest to restrict most of your API keys, for example on my situations all API keys linked with "iOS" platforms are restricted for iOS only and contain a specific bundle identity. This will not only prevent misuse of the APIs but also prevent unauthorised applications/individuals from using your assigned API keys.

Comment: Grate catch @Sharkes. Just to addition of this solution if you preceding with google-services file from Firebase solution, you need to update the following in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_key"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
       <meta-data

Comment: Is it safe to delete it, given that It's nowhere to be found in the codebase?

Comment: If there's usage scenario then proceed to delete it @keriackus

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you enabled a new API in your Google console account that was not enabled before